# How do you troubleshoot why the command "systemctl is-system-running" stuck in "starting"

Tags: 19.10, systemd

This is on 19.10.

when i run the command `systemctl is-system-running` i get a response `starting`. Everything is running ok, and I can RDP (XRDP) into it and do most work. I have a package that I am trying to install and the postinit file in dpkg/info is checking that command and failing because my system is still "starting". even after a few hours.

I dont know where to begin (besides googling, which came up empty) troubleshooting this. any ideas?

Is there a way to find the offending service? I assume that a service hasnt started that is supposed to.